# Custom Search API works on local host but request timeout on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, timeout, google-custom-search

I am currently building an image search api with code as follows:

When i try to run in on local using heroku local in terminal, it works as expected, i.e when i enter the following url into the browser:
http://localhost:5000/api/imagesearch/1984

It returns the desired search results. However, when the app is deployed on Heroku and i run the app using heroku open, I get an Application Error. I have checked the log and it seems like it is a H12 request timeout error.

It seems to me that the app is taking a very long time (much longer than when i run it on localhost such that there is a request timeout error) to get a response from google custom search when I am accessing using Heroku compared to when i am accessing via local host but i am unable to figure out why that is the case or what else can i do to work this issue.

Would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks

```
var Search = require('../models/history.js');

var GoogleSearch = require('google-search');
var googleSearch = new GoogleSearch({
    key: "XXXX",
    cx: "YYY"
}); 

function ImgSearchHandler () {

this.retrieveSearchResults = function (req, res) {
    var newSearch = new Search();
    newSearch.term = req.params.query;
    newSearch.when = new Date();

    newSearch.save(function (err){
        console.log("saving...");
        if (err) {throw err;}
        var offset;
        if (req.query.offset) {
            offset = req.query.offset;
        } else {
            offset = 1;
        }

        //res.send('save and retrieve');

        googleSearch.build({
          q: req.params.query,
          searchType: "image",
          fileType:'png jpg gif jpeg',
          num: 1, // Number of search results to return between 1 and 10, inclusive 
          start: offset,
        }, function(error, response) {      
            if (error)  {
                throw error;
            }

            var results = [];
            response.items.forEach(function (element){
                var url = element.link;
                var context = element.image.contextLink;
                var snippet = element.snippet;
                var thumbnail = element.image.thumbnailLink;

                var result = {url: url, snippet: snippet, thumbnail: thumbnail, context: context};
                results.push(result);

            });

            res.json(results);
          //res.json(response.items);
        });

    });

}

}

module.exports = ImgSearchHandler;
```

Comment: Perhaps `res.json` is not being called, i.e. there is an error on Heroku that is not happening locally that you are also not properly catching or handling